# How can I merge two dataframes if two cols have to be the same?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames. For example the `df1` looks like:

```
Name Month Number       
1.H  1      8
2.H  2      7  
3.H  3      6 
4.A  1      9
5.A  2      10
6.A  3      11
```

And `df2` looks like:

```
Name Month index      
1.H    1      3
2.H    2      2  
3.H    3      1
4.A    1      3 
5.A    2      5
6.A    3      9
```

And I want to merge it to the following `df`:

```
  Name Month Number index
  1.H  1    8       3
  2.H  2    7       2
  3.H  3    6       1
  4.A  1    9       3
  5.A  2    10      5
  6.A  3    11      9
```

How can I merge the two df's to this `df`?

**I have already tried the `merge` function `by.x` and `by.y` but that only allows merging by one column, but I want also the second column.**

Comment: try `merge(df1, df2)`

Comment: Who told you that `by.x` and `by.y` allows to merge only by one column? Where is that written? The documentation doesn't say so. Did you even try doing it by several columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge on more than one column at a time:

```
merge(df1, df2, by = c('Name', 'Month'))
```

In fact, that should be the default, as the default value of `by` is `intersect(names(df1), names(df2))`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to do this. The other two answers give base ways to do it. Here are two other ways with packages.

You can also use the `sqldf` package:

```
sqldf("select a.*, b.index from df1 as a join df2 as b on a.name = b.name and a.month = b.month")
```

You can use the `dplyr` package:

```
inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("name", "month"))
```